# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on distance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I reviewed the other answers and they don't answer my problem for the HammingDistance.

I am giving it an infinity for the distance.

```py
import sys
def DistanceBetweenPatternAndStrings(pattern, dna):
    k = pattern
        distance = 0
        for i in range(len(dna) - len(pattern)+1):
            HammingDistance = sys.maxsize
            for j in range(len(dna) - len(pattern)+1): 
                pattern2 = dna[j:j+len(pattern)]
                if HammingDistance > HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2):
                    HammingDistance = HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2)
            distance = distance + HammingDistance
            return distance

def HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2):
    diff = 0
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(pattern, pattern2):
        if ch1 != ch2:
            diff +=1
    return diff
```

I should get the distance without errors but I am getting this:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

in the

```
if HammingDistance > HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2)
```

Comment: HammingDistance is a variable. Here in your if statement your are calling it as a function '()' when you do HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the distance calculation. The problem is that you have a variable and a method with the same name. You should *never* do that.

You have `HammingDistance` defined as a method:

```py
def HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2):
    ...
```

You also have `HammingDistance` defined as an `int`:

```py
HammingDistance = sys.maxsize
```

When you did this:

```
HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2)
```

The interpreter will call the nearest definition, which is the `HammingDistance` defined as an `int`, **NOT** your `HammingDistance` method. That is why you get the "*'int' object is not callable*" error.

Simply rename your local variable to something else, to distinguish it from the method.

```py
hamming_distance = sys.maxsize
for j in range(len(dna) - len(pattern)+1): 
    pattern2 = dna[j:j+len(pattern)]
    if hamming_distance > HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2):
        hamming_distance = HammingDistance(pattern, pattern2)
distance = distance + hamming_distance
```